# I am trying to add new values to key value pair in mongodb (mongoose) in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema with categories field :

```
categories{
  category_1 : [],
  category_2 : [],
  category_3 :[] ,
}
```

I am trying to push contestant's id in a particular category so after pushing id in category_1 ,it should be something like this:

```
categories{
  category_1 : [contestant_id],
  category_2 : [],
  category_3 :[] ,
}
```

These are the fields in an actual database .

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee7e804311aa55316e5b20a"), "tournament_id" : "demo@gmail.com", "name" : "Updated Tournament", "event_date" : "2020-06-30", "last_entry" : "2020-06-29", "entry_fee" : 6000, "categories" : { "MU10" : [ ], "FU18" : [ ], "MU7" : [ ], "MU8" : [ ], "MSENIOR" : [ ], "FSENIOR" : [ ], "MU9" : [ ], "FU10" : [ ] }, "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: Do you want to insert a document or do you want to update one?

Comment: I want to update one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below:

```
db.yourcollection.update(
   { _id: ObjectId("5ee7e804311aa55316e5b20a") },
   { $push: { "categories.MU10": "contestant_id" } }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked . I was doing this without the quotes and it threw error and I  assumed that it won't work with the quotes without even trying.

Comment: What if I want to use a variable  instead of MU10 as I am unable to use back tick .

Comment: Why are you unable to use backtick? it should be sth like: ``"categories.${category_variable}"`` inside backticks

Comment: Can you send the way you are using them?

Comment: backtick"categories.${category}"backtick

Comment: It sounds right. You should use double quotes inside the backticks.

Comment: If it doesn’t work (it should) you can do a trick and define a string above and use that. Like let query=backtick”categories.backtick + category + backtick”backtick

Comment: I did the exact thing before but surprisingly this worked [--categories.${category}--] where -- is backtick

Comment: Yeah! It should! Because it creates a string :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `$push` to append to Array:

For example to append `contestant_id` to the `category_1` array:

```
db.TABLE.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $push: { category_1: contestant_id } }
)
```

Comment: categories is a type of object and category_1 , category_2 are key value pair of type array .

Answer (score 0):

So, as I'm understanding right, you want to push `contestant_id` to `categories.category_1`, right?

To do this, just simply use

```
categories.category_1.push(contestant_id)
```

Comment: I think it won't work as I am updating the values in mongodb